# How to write Spark data frame to xml file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Sample :

```
scala> Frame.show()

|year| make|model|             comment|blank|
|2012|Tesla|    S|          No comment|    R|
|1997| Ford| E350|Go get one now th...|    L|
|2015|Chevy| Volt|                 Try|    M|
```

to

```
<item>
    <'year'>2012<'/year'>
    <'make'>Tesla<'/make'>
    <'model'>S<'/mode'>
</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest approach is to use XML writer from [`spark-xml`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml):

```
val path: String = ???
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rootTag", "items")
  .option("rowTag", "item")
  .save(path)
```

If for some reason it doesn't fit your needs you can dump records individually and `saveAsTextFile`:

```
def dumpXML(row: Row): String = ???
df.rdd.map(dumpXML).saveAsTextFile(path)
```

You can add root element using for example `mapPartitions`.

Comment: I'm getting Null Point exception.        1 method tried : spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.3.2

Comment: It is hard to so what may go wrong without the context. NPE in Spark SQL usually mean some kind of nested access.

Comment: What if i have to add some constant in the xml ?

Comment: @zero323, would you be willing to elaborate on how `mapPartitions` could be used to add a root element for a bunch of XML records written via `saveAsTextFile`?

Comment: what would be the tag used to write a nested xml like this - 

<ENVELOPE>
    <header>
        <nursuryObject>
            <nursuryEvent>UPDATE</nursuryEvent>
            <nursuryObjectId>SDSDS</nursuryObjectId>
            <nursuryObjectOwner>ABCDE</nursuryObjectOwner>
            <nursuryObjectType>PQRST</nursuryObjectType>
        </nursuryObject>
        <messageObject>
            <messageId>123</messageId>
            <timeStamp>2011-02-28T09:27:02TIMESTAMP</timeStamp>
        </messageObject>